# Nativescript: TypeError: Invalid Version: 1.?2.0

Tags: nativescript, package.json, nativescript-plugin

I'm getting the error while installing the plugin.
`TypeError: Invalid Version: 1.?2.0`

I've created the plugin for NativeScript.
Here is how my `package.json` looks like.

```
    {
      "name": "nativescript-toaster",
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "main": "index.js",
      "nativescript": {
        "platforms": {
          "android": "1.​2.0"
        }
      }
    }
```

As described in some forums I've tried to remove the `android` entries from `package.json` of NS projects, and clean cache `npm cache clean`. But as I add android platform `tns platform add android` it comes again.

Please share if you've any idea about this.

Thanks Guys

Comment: Did you figure out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. In my case, I was trying to include iOS and Android native code; I tried changing it like this: "1.3.0" , and the error disappeared.

Comment: What did you change to "1.3.0" ?  "android" or "version" or something else?  Please edit your answer to include this information.

Comment: I changed the value to 1.3.0, so it ended up like :

{
  "name": "my-plugin",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "nativescript": {
    "platforms": {
      "ios": "1.3.0",
      "android": "1.3.0"
    }
  }
}

Also, I found a working example that used : 
"nativescript": {
        "platforms": {
            "android": "3.0.0",
            "ios": "3.0.0"
        }
    },

Comment: Awesome, could you please edit your answer to include that information?

Comment: Just to add to my prior comment: the example where "3.0.0" is used can be found at [link](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/ui-plugin-custom)